# trying to use boost::bind with members function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

I'm trying to use `boost::bind` and `boost::asio` from  std::thread that created in member function that calls different member function (I hope that I make sense)

this is my code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <fucntional>

template<typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    void run(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/,
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* th,bool& flag)
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            //do somthing;
             th->expires_at(th->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::minutes(1));
             th->async_wait(boost::bind(&A< T>::run,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error, th, flag));
        }
    }
    
    void initBoost(bool& flag)
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer th(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
        th.async_wait(boost::bind(&A<T>::run,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error, &th, flag));
        io.run();
    }
    
    void init()
    {
        bool flag;
        std::thread t(&A<T>::initBoost,this,std::ref(flag));
        t.detach();
        
    }
};


int main()
{
 A<int> a;
 a.init();
 std::cout <<"end\n";
 return 0;
}
```

[link to compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/j5hd8n).
and this is the errors that I'm getting:

```
   In file included from <source>:4:0:    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread: In instantiation of 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >':    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:127:22:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A<int>::*)(bool&); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<bool>}]'    
<source>:33:21:   required from 'void A<T>::init() [with T = int]'    
<source>:42:9:   required from here    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:240:2: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >::_Indices)'    
  operator()()    
  ^~~~~~~~    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:231:4: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int ..._Ind> decltype (std::__invoke((_S_declval<_Ind>)()...)) std::thread::_Invoker<_Tuple>::_M_invoke(std::_Index_tuple<_Ind ...>) [with long unsigned int ..._Ind = {_Ind ...}; _Tuple = std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&>]    
    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)    
    ^~~~~~~~~ 
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:231:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:   
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread: In substitution of 'template<long unsigned int ..._Ind> decltype (std::__invoke(_S_declval<_Ind>()...)) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >::_M_invoke<_Ind ...>(std::_Index_tuple<_Ind1 ...>) [with long unsigned int ..._Ind = {0, 1}]':    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:240:2:   required from 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >'    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:127:22:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A<int>::*)(bool&); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<bool>}]'    
<source>:33:21:   required from 'void A<T>::init() [with T = int]'    
<source>:42:9:   required from here    
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:233:29: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >, bool&)' 
    -> decltype(std::__invoke(_S_declval<_Ind>()...))
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/tuple:41:0,    
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:37,   
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/memory:80,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/detail/addressof.hpp:21,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:19,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,    
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /celibs/boost_1_64_0/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from <source>:2:  
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr typename std::__invoke_result<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr typename std::__invoke_result<_Functor, _ArgTypes>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A<int>::*)(bool&); _Args = {bool&}]':

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:233:29:   required by substitution of 'template<long unsigned int ..._Ind> decltype (std::__invoke(_S_declval<_Ind>()...)) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >::_M_invoke<_Ind ...>(std::_Index_tuple<_Ind1 ...>) [with long unsigned int ..._Ind = {0, 1}]'

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:240:2:   required from 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&> >'

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/thread:127:22:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (A<int>::*)(bool&); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<bool>}]'

<source>:33:21:   required from 'void A<T>::init() [with T = int]'

<source>:42:9:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-7.3.0/include/c++/7.3.0/bits/invoke.h:89:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::__invoke_result<void (A<int>::*)(bool&), bool&>'
```

Comment: I believe you ought to write `A` instead of `A<T>` whenever you do stuff inside template class `A`. Don't know why though - at least that's what made similar stuff work in my code.

Comment: What is the type of the expression `&flag`? What is the type of the argument for `initBoost`? And you might want to do some research about [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Comment: Also note that when the `main` function returns, the whole process exits, which includes killing all threads. You should only end the main thread (which isn't possible through standard C++ for some reason, you need to use platform-specific calls to do that, like [`pthread_exit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) on POSIX systems).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I fix the `&flag`, change to `std::thread t(&A<T>::initBoost,std::ref(flag));` but still the same

Comment: (other than a typo in `#include <functional>`) the code you've posted compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/c6nKj3

Comment: thanks - didn't pay attention to the typo - so @Someprogrammerdude solve my problem with the std::ref and &